# DataFrame save at each iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to save some values from my training model as DataFrame which works okay but it only save a data for the first loop and it stops. I have tried to put it in a For loop but didn't help. What ways is available for me please to save for the whole training?

```
 df=pd.DataFrame({'Image_Name':names_preds, 'Target':targets.detach(), 'Prediction':preds.detach()})
            print(df)
            df.to_csv(r'test5.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: can you please include the entire script? Its clear you're using pandas and numpy, is there anything else you are importing/using?

Comment: PyTorch to run the training model. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: @samman i don't think we wanted what we thought we wanted

Comment: We don't need all of the pytorch, ML, and CLI stuff. mock up a dataframe and show us what you're trying to do

Comment: I have included the code concerning the DataFrame only. I need to save those values at each iteration. At the moment the DF only save one iteration.

Comment: Read through the link i posted above. it's not at all clear what's going on.

Comment: Sorry not sure how i could duplicate the issue i am having. As i said I am trying to save the values in my dataframe at each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding mode='a' sorted the issue.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Image_Name':names_preds, 'Target':targets.detach(), 'Prediction':preds.detach()})
            print(df)
            df.to_csv(r'test5.csv',mode='a', index=False)
```